# draw only outline of multiple histograms in ggplot to clearly visualize

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is code to generate two histograms. But due to significant overlap, it is difficult to see each distibution clearly.

How can I can only plot a thicker outline of each histogram and remove the vertical lines/bars.

[image]

Desirable histogram should look this -

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

A <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
B <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.1, sd = 1.3)

tbl <- tibble(A, B) %>%
  # pivot longer
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = "Distributions",
               values_to = "values")

ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = values,
           col = Distributions,
           fill = Distributions)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 50,
                 alpha = 0.3,
                 position = "identity") + 
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine a borderless histogram with a `geom_step()` layer for the outline.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.1.1
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.1

A <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
B <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.1, sd = 1.3)

tbl <- tibble(A, B) %>%
  # pivot longer
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = "Distributions",
               values_to = "values")

ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = values,
           col = Distributions,
           fill = Distributions)) + 
  geom_step(
    stat = "bin", bins = 50,
    direction = "mid"
  ) +
  geom_histogram(
    bins = 50, alpha = 0.3, colour = NA,
    position = "identity"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>